# Singleton Fragment in kotlin gives compilation error ktNameReferenceException

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, singleton, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to make a singleton fragment by doing this:

```
object MyFragment: BottomSheetDialogFragment {...}
```

But while building the project it gives compile time exception:

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Failed to generate expression: ktNameReferenceException
```

What is wrong with the above approach?

Comment: AFAIK fragments shouldn't be singletons [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839152/fragment-as-a-singleton-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyFragment: BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    companion object {
        val INSTANCE : MyFragment = ...
    }
}
```

But my questions is why do you need it? What problem are you trying to solve? It's a bit weird and unexpected approach I would say